# Cypress run test on condition

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm not clear on how to run tests only if an async condition is satisfied: if an element is present on the page.

It'd be something like that, which obviously doesn't work. I can see the alert "enabled", but the nested test "Run proper tests" won't run. What is the right way to do this?
Of course, this is simplified, there are a lot of more tests, not just 1.

```
context("table", () => {

    it("Check availability", () => {
        cy.get("div.table").then($div => {
            if (!Cypress.$(".header[title]", $div).length) {
                alert("not enabled");
            } else {
                alert("enabled");
                it("Run proper tests", () => {...});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a new instance and use a variable

```js
context("table", () => {

let result

    it("Check availability", () => {
        cy.get("div.table").then($div => {
            if (!Cypress.$(".header[title]", $div).length) {
                alert("not enabled");
                result='fail'
            } 
            else {
                alert("enabled");
            }
     })

     it("Run proper tests", () => {
          if (result === 'fail') {
          console.log('not enabled')
          }
          else {
           Run proper test
               }
     })
})
```

Comment: That is the solution I've adopted before even seeing your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Mocha's [pending tests](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests) feature via `this.skip()`:

```js
context("table", () => {

    it("Run proper tests", () => {
        cy.get("div.table").then(function($div) {
            if (!Cypress.$(".header[title]", $div).length) {
                this.skip()
            } else {
                // Run proper test
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is how a skipped test is displayed in the Cypress runner:
[image]