# Skip test in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I skip the whole set of tests in a spec file only in a specific case?
Sample code:

```
context("Conditional run", () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.get("div").then($div => {
            if (!Cypress.$("div[title='OK']", $comp).length) {
                // continue with the tests
            } else {
                // skip ALL the tests
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Something similar on answer from @MikhailBolotov [Cypress run test on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69758663/19867290) -  your question BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beforeEach()` allows skipping.

Try this

```js
  context("Conditional run", () => {
    let skip = false;
    before(() => {
        cy.get("div").then(($div) => {
            if (!Cypress.$("div[title='OK']", $comp).length) {
                skip = false
            } else {
                skip = true
            }
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function() {    // use regular function here
      if (skip) this.skip();
    })
  });
```

It might also work just putting the skip call in the before, since you want to skip all tests.

```js
  context("Conditional run", () => {

    before(function() {    // use regular function here

        cy.get("div").then(function($div) {    // not sure if function is needed here
            if (Cypress.$("div[title='OK']", $comp).length) {
                this.skip();
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: where is this `skip()` documented? I couldn't find it

Comment: It's part of Mocha - Cypress runner is built on Mocha.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'skip')`. `skip` is not recognised

Comment: Sounds like you did not use `function()`?

Comment: Maybe `function()` syntax is needed on the `.then()` as well.

Comment: I thought Cypress was so smart it would have figure the context out by itself :)

Comment: LOL Yeah, it's bound by the Javascript language rules. Arrow functions ironically introduced to solve some other problems with `this`. But I wonder if there's a `Cypress.Mocha.skip()` or something similar. Will have to check it out.